# AWS - How to create a generic dns in front of load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I have an internal load-balancer in aws and I am able to access it successfully from my office network.

I want to put this behind a generic dns so using Route 53, I created a private hosted zone "domain.com"
and then created A record "project.domain.com" pointing to the lb dns mentioned below:

DNS of internal load balancer -> internal-lb-99999999999999.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/

But now from my office network I tried to access "project.domain.com" and it did not work. AM I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For the setup i have used in the past we do not have the `http://` part in the value of the A record in DNS just the load balancer DNS.

Also have you validated that your VPC has DNS resolution enabled?

Comment: yes DNS resolution is enabled, and if i access the project.domain.com from within VPC then it works fine.

Comment: How does your corp network connect to that VPC? is it via VPN/Direct Connect/Other?

Comment: direct connect, and thanks for pointing on that dns name, that was a typo but it is still not working.